# Autoload file for a simple PHP unit test not working

Tags: php, phpunit, autoload

I am trying to get familiar with PHPUnit, I followed all the instructions [`here("Getting Started with PHPUnit 7")`](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html).

I copy/pasted those `src/Email.php` and `tests/EmailTest.php` code sources. My problem is when I try to run `./phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/EmailTest`. The documentation says I must create that  `src/autoload.php`, so I followed the first example mentioned [`here("Autoloading Classes")`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php):

```
<?php
// Maybe I do not need this require_once() stuff?
require_once('src/Email.php');
require_once('tests/EmailTest.php');

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});

$obj  = new Email('bart.simpson@outlook.com');
$obj2 = new EmailTest(); 
?>
```

but I am getting this error message when I test with the previous command:

```
PHP Error:  Call to private Email::__construct() from context 'PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader' in /var/www/html/php_project/src/autoload.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:53
PHP   3. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:159
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleArguments() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:170
PHP   5. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleBootstrap() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:896
PHP   6. PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:1035
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php:45
PHP   8. include_once() /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php:57
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to private Email::__construct() from context 'PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader' in /var/www/html/php_project/src/autoload.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(57): include_once()
#1 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(45): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load('/var/www/html/p...')
#2 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(1035): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad('src/autoload.ph...')
#3 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(896): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleBootstrap('src/autoload.ph...')
#4 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(170): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleArguments(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(159): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#6 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(53): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#7 {main}
  in /var/www/html/php_project/src/autoload.php on line 9
```

I used such things long time ago, if you can help me to refresh ...

P.S. Given my setup, I rather run `./vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/EmailTest` but that does not make difference with what I have written so far.

**EDIT:**

Following the below comments, I made the constructor public and run again the test, I got this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'tests/EmailTest' could not be found in 'tests/EmailTest.php'. in /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:99
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(130): PHPUnit\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader->load('tests/EmailTest', 'tests/EmailTest...')
#1 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(78): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass('tests/EmailTest', '')
#2 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(180): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest('tests/EmailTest', '', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(159): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#4 /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(53): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/php_project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php on line 99
```

[image]

Comment: The error message indicates that the constructor of class `Email` is marked `private` rather than a problem with class loading. So you cannot do `new Email()` outside the class.

Comment: You are using phpunit via Composer. I think it would be simpler if you also used Composer for autoloading instead of manually creating a autoload.php and messing with `spl_autoload_register`. Is that OK or do you explicitly expect a solution in the setup described? For me it just works if I follow the instructions like described: https://i.imgur.com/j5OgU9J.png

Comment: Yes, I am using PHPUnit via Composer, sorry for the late reply, and thank you for the screenshot, I will try them in a short moment

Comment: I followed your instructions and it works well (I just added `require_once('src/Email.php')` in `tests/EmailTest.php` and then remove `src/autoload.php` and it works). So if you transofrm your comment into an answer, I will be glad to upvote and accept it. @TobiasK

Comment: Good! However, it shouldn't be necessary to manually `require` the source class in your testcase. This will also become very error-prone and tedious if you get more and more classes in your project. I'll write an more extensive answer and include my suggested setup.

Comment: If I remove that `require()` I get errors saying it does not find the `Email` class. Ok, thank you for the attention and the efforts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used Composer to install PHPUnit in my opinion it is best to also use it for autoloading and not bother with that yourself.

Allow me to share my (opinionated) setup for PHP projects:

- Classes in `./src/`
- Test-Case classes in `./tests/`

*composer.json* (check [PSR-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) rather than `classmap` in a bigger project):

```json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/"
    ]
},
```

*phpunit.xml* (used to save settings so you don't have to pass it in CLI all the time):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Tests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Then I can just call `./vendor/bin/phpunit` without options and it runs all my tests.

---

> Using `classmap` it may be necessary to run `composer dump` to regenerate autoload files after adding new classes/files.

Comment: +1: `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"` way to go for composer based projects. sometimes there is more in the bootstrap, consult the phpunit XML configuraiton file for more settings apart from bootstrag and try to eliminate the rest over time. the less a bootstrap contains, the easier a project is to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encoutered few issues with class autoloading in phpunit. I hope this would help someone. User psr-4. Make sure the sub-folder case name matches the namespace you set in the class.

```
{
  "autoload-dev": {
       "psr-4": {
          "Tests\\": "tests/"
      }
 }
```

Then place your phpunit.xml file in the root directory.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Your Test Suit name">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```